# Setting Jupyter Notebook Server Using Mac

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a mac and want to set it as a Jupyter Notebook server so that I could connect it using browser through the internet when I'm not at home. But I cannot find instruction online. Is my idea feasible and easy to realize? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set host to 0.0.0.0 to expose the server to your internal network. Then follow these instructions to open it up externally.

https://medium.com/botfuel/how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet-c31532d741cc